# defuse/php-encryption - same key doesn't work on different machines?

Tags: php, security, encryption, cryptography

I am quite new to the encryption subject.

What I need in my PHP scripts is a simple synchronous encryption for a value I need to store in DB. So I already read several tutorials and posts and decided to go with defuse/php-encryption.

The approach seems quite straight forward

generate a key and use it for further decrypt/encrypt

Encrypt

1. encrypt data with the key
2. store encrypted in DB

Decrypt

1. read encrypted data from DB
2. decrypt it with the key
3. have fun with the plain text

I downloaded v2 of the defuse/php-encryption library from
https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/releases

generated the key

```
Key::createNewRandomKey();
echo $key->saveToAsciiSafeString();
```

stored it - for testing - just directly in a `getKey()` method of my PHP script.

I encrypt/decrypt like this

```
Crypto::encrypt($plainText, Key::loadFromAsciiSafeString($key));
Crypto::decrypt($encryptedText, Key::loadFromAsciiSafeString($key));
```

which works like a charm as long as I stay on my machine.

Unfortunately when I switch to my Mac laptop and run the same code - with the same key (!), I get an exception:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'Defuse\Crypto\Exception\BadFormatException' with message 'Invalid
>   header.' in
>   phar://classes/encryption/defuse-crypto.phar/src/Encoding.php:177

Stack trace:

```
#0 phar://classes/encryption/defuse-crypto.phar/src/Key.php(38): Defuse\Crypto\Encoding::loadBytesFromChecksummedAsciiSafeString('\xDE\xF0\x00\x00', 'c622e3d4793e511...')
```

If I generate a new key on the Mac - it works. But this leaves a very uneasy feeling because I have to be able to decrypt the data with the same key on any machine.

If one day the server crashes and I will have to restore the data on a different machine getting such nice errors while decrypting - I will be doomed :-)

I am definitely doing something wrong. I can use any advice you can provide.

thanks

Comment: Sorry about the previous comment, by default the ciphertext seems stored as hex. Not very efficient, but hey. Do you maybe use different versions of defuse?

Comment: If you have ciphertext in hexadecimals you should be able to print it on both machines and compare. Could you do that? Same for the key.

Comment: Also note [this change](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/commit/793b50c516f539318acb144f1ec8aae3882ecffd?diff=unified)

Comment: @Maarten, thanks for the fast comment. Unfortunately it is exact the same code base and the same library. I just check out from the repository. But it is a good hint - perhaps it has to do with the encoding of the PHP file? - I just pasted the generated key in the function getKey()  -> return "here comes the key string";

Comment: Maybe you could put some runtime  version numbers & input / output in the question? Unless somebody experienced the exact same issue there is not much to go on.

Comment: Can you generate a new garbage key (i.e. one you won't be using) and some sample ciphertexts and include them in your answer so we can attempt to diagnose the issue? Also, what PHP version are you running on each?